# How do I open mail using vim?

Tags: mail-command

I scheduled a task using `at`. The output of the scheduled job was sent to `mail`. But the output is quite huge; I prefer reading it in a text editor.

Additionally, I don't want to forward the mail, I just want to read locally.

I hope there is a standard way for all *nix. But I use OS X and RedHat.

Comment: which ditribution are you using (ubuntu ? redhat ? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pipe mail to vim, at least on my test system (RHEL 6.7) it worked.

```
 mail | vim -
```

the `vim -` tells vim to read from standard input

you should see output that say's:

```
Vim: reading from stdin...
```

at that point just press the number of the mail item you want to read, IE `1` to read the first message,then press <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> to push it forward.

Answer (score 4):

You can open the mail spool file (usually `/var/spool/mail/<username>`) in `vim`, but it will contain header information that you probably don't want. Your best bet is to open the message in your mail program, save the message to a file, then open the newly saved file in vim. You'll still have some header information, but much less of it than if you open the mail spool file directly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following lines in my `~/.muttrc` so that I can press <kbd>F6</kbd> while viewing any message to pipe it into `less`.

```
macro generic <f6> "|less\n" "view with less"
macro index   <f6> "|less\n" "view with less"
macro attach  <f6> "|less\n" "view with less"
macro pager   <f6> "|less\n" "view with less"
```

IMO, `less` is the right tool for this job, but if you insist on `vim` then change all occurrences of `less` above to `vim -`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm answering your question correctly, but you can use [The Mutt E-Mail Client](http://www.mutt.org/) and configure it to use Vim.